# Why to post big blind in online poker?

Tags: online, poker-strategy, poker-tools, blinds

All the times, before you sit on a table in online playing portal you are asked 
"Click to post BB" to play fast.
Why should I click on that button showing to post the big blind option?

Answer (score 6):

It is just a rule of poker.  When you take a seat you must wait for the BB to come to you before you can start playing.   Or you can post a BB to start playing immediately.

Imagine this scenario.  A player stands up when the BB gets to them then sits back down when the SB passes.  If they don't pay to play then they have avoided paying the binds.

If you sit down in late position then it might be worth paying a BB to play immediately.  If you are in early position it is not worth paying a BB to play immediately as you are not only playing out of position but you only have to wait a round or two to come in on the BB.

Answer (score 4):

This is to prevent people from gaining an advantage by coming in for free than not playing the blind when it comes to them. Common rule, although not particularly standard in all venues.

Answer (score 4):

They must include this button.

Imagine the scenario, you sit down at a table and someone comes to the door.  Without this button the game would force you to pay the BB out of turn.  And you could potentially miss a hand.

In order to participate in a round of poker (one full revolution of the dealer button) you must post a BB and a SB.  If you skip this process you either must skip the entire round and wait for the BB to come to you, or you must pay the BB you missed to enter into the revolution.

If you sit down at a table you have a choice to either wait for the BB to come to you, or you can "buy into" the current revolution.  But since no one can force you to "buy in" until the "BB" you must always be given the option to "buy in" early.

Answer (score 0):

it is an easy poker hustle, to never pay blinds, when they do not require you to pay a blind for your first hand, it used to be common not to have to post. some managers, felt and rightly so it is bit easier to get a game started when a post is required for the first hand, players will sit down at the table do they do not miss that free hand. The downside, or other side is a rule that says a player assumes all obligations of a seat, when they take the seat, including missed blinds, which was the common rule up until 1990 or so and it also makes a crappy game when a number of players are sitting out. the problem with the old rule id the guys that would hustle the rules than often people would lock up a seat then go eat or go up to the room for fun time before playing. there are some advantages to it, arguably posting a blind late is more advantages then posting under the gun, and it is also a table image thing, a player whom will wait rather then post, had just announced he is a tight player to the table, posting right away conveys a bit of a looser image, and of course time is money and We came to play so lets get into action ASAP.